# A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, gac

Using nuget I installed both System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll and Newtonsoft.Json.dll

```
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="8.0.3" targetFramework="net45" />
```

> A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

NOTE : Newtonsoft.Json with version="8.0.3" is already is in use. So how to include two Newtonsoft.Json versions ??

because as error is stating that `System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll`doesn't find the Newtonsoft.Json with version 4.5.0.0

Answer (score 0):

In order to make this, you've to add one of dll in to a folder named V-1 inside bin folder. Then made config changes like this, (Place the appropriate values for labels in <> e.g. AssemblyName, Version-1 etc.)

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>        
    <assemblyIdentity name="<AssemblyName>" publicKeyToken="<PublicKeyToken>" culture="neutral" />
        <codeBase version="<Version-1>" href="V-1\<AssemblyName>.dll" />
        <codeBase version="<Version-2>" href="<AssemblyName>.dll" />
    </dependentAssembly>      
</assemblyBinding>
```

Then,

1. Please open **Solution Explorer** in visual studio
2. Open **References** under the project
3. Select **Newtsoft** reference and go to its properties.
4. Set **Specific Version = True**  and **Copy Local = False**
5. Make sure your output directory does not contain this dll in it.